# Usage of the relative pronoun 'what'

Tags: grammar, pronouns, writing, relative-pronouns, learning

In my grammar books it's written the relative pronoun 'What' is used only in singular.

Does this mean It's used just with a singular nouns. For ex, "What goal you want to accomplish" is a correct sentence. But "what goals you want to accomplish" is incorrect.

Did I get it right?

Comment: Neither of your examples is correct. You need "What goal(s) **do** you want to accomplish? Note that in these examples "what" is an interrogative determinative, not a relative pronoun.

Comment: "He failed in things what he attempted" Vs "he failed in things which he attempted" which one is right?

Comment: Your second example is the correct one, but note that you can say "He failed in what he attempted".

Comment: Just a last question I want to ask for a good understanding. The first sentence is incorrect because 'what' is not used as pronoun of plural noun, right?

Comment: No, it's because "what" can't be used as a relative pronoun except in constructions like the one I used.